# After implementing Realm my Android App taking too much time to launch the app

Tags: android, realm, launch-time

Before implementing Realm in my Android application the launch time was less than 2 seconds, but after implementing it the minimum launch time is 8 seconds and maximum launch time is 6 minutes.

I am using only 3 tables with Realm.
Is there any setting or configuration required for this?

Comment: Do you have a class that extends `Application`, if yes can you add it. Or how you init `Realm` config. And one more question what you mean about launching (your building project process takes so many time or you see white screen on app start) And did you tried by disabling instant run ?

Comment: The first Realm instance takes a bit time to init the schemas, but 3 tables should never take 8 secs - 6 minutes. Could you please do some profiling to see which part takes time?

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz, I do have class that extends Application but I didn't put any kind of code their related to Realm. I have below lines of code in activity to initialize the realm 'try {
 realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).build();
 realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
}
catch (RealmMigrationNeededException e){
 try {
  Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
  //Realm file has been deleted.
  return Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
 } catch (Exception ex){
  ex.printStackTrace();
  //No Realm file to remove.
 }
}'

Comment: If `catch (RealmMigrationNeededException e)` is just for testing purpose, you can use `RealmConfiguration.Builder.deleteIfMigrationNeeded()` instead.

Comment: Do you call `Realm.compactRealm()` on initialization or something?

Comment: @AjaySharma Have you find any solution to reduce compilation time? I am facing same problem. It takes 8 to 10 mins to build.